# RavenDB migration from 3.5 to 5.0.3 throws duplicate key error

Tags: ravendb, ravendb5, ravendb-3.5

I am moving a RavenDB instance from 3.5 (build #35295) to 5.0.3 (the latest at the time of writing). I start the migration through the Settings > Import Data > From RavenDB. I only include documents and indexes. The old database used revisions for a while, but stopped doing that. The document the migration fails on is not one that has revisions.

After importing about 650k documents, RavenDB throws the error

```
An item with the same key has already been added. Key: [Value: Redacted description, GlobalSortOrder: -1, PropertyId: 342, Value: Redacted description, GlobalSortOrder: -1, PropertyId: 342]
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: [Value: Redacted description, GlobalSortOrder: -1, PropertyId: 342, Value: Redacted description, GlobalSortOrder: -1, PropertyId: 342]
   at System.Collections.Generic.TreeSet`1.AddIfNotPresent(T item)
   at System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   at Sparrow.Json.CachedProperties.UnlikelyGetProperty(LazyStringValue propName) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.0\50011\src\Sparrow\Json\CachedProperties.cs:line 157
   at Sparrow.Json.BlittableJsonDocumentBuilder.ReadInternal[TWriteStrategy]() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.0\50011\src\Sparrow\Json\BlittableJsonDocumentBuilder.cs:line 296
   at Sparrow.Json.Parsing.UnmanagedJsonParserHelper.ReadObject(BlittableJsonDocumentBuilder builder, PeepingTomStream peepingTomStream, UnmanagedJsonParser parser, MemoryBuffer buffer) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.0\50011\src\Sparrow\Json\Parsing\UnmanagedJsonParserHelper.cs:line 96
   at Raven.Server.Smuggler.Documents.StreamSource.ReadDocuments(INewDocumentActions actions)+MoveNext() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.0\50011\src\Raven.Server\Smuggler\Documents\StreamSource.cs:line 1184
   at Raven.Server.Smuggler.Documents.DatabaseSmuggler.ProcessDocuments(SmugglerResult result, BuildVersionType buildType) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.0\50011\src\Raven.Server\Smuggler\Documents\DatabaseSmuggler.cs:line 612
   at Raven.Server.Smuggler.Documents.DatabaseSmuggler.ProcessType(DatabaseItemType type, SmugglerResult result, BuildVersionType buildType, Boolean ensureStepsProcessed) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.0\50011\src\Raven.Server\Smuggler\Documents\DatabaseSmuggler.cs:line 190
   at Raven.Server.Smuggler.Documents.DatabaseSmuggler.Execute(Boolean ensureStepsProcessed, Boolean isLastFile) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.0\50011\src\Raven.Server\Smuggler\Documents\DatabaseSmuggler.cs:line 95
   at Raven.Server.Smuggler.Migration.Migrator_V3.MigrateDatabase(String json, Boolean readLegacyEtag) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.0\50011\src\Raven.Server\Smuggler\Migration\Migrator_V3.cs:line 338
   at Raven.Server.Smuggler.Migration.Migrator_V3.Execute() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.0\50011\src\Raven.Server\Smuggler\Migration\Migrator_V3.cs:line 99
   at Raven.Server.Smuggler.Migration.Migrator.<>c__DisplayClass15_1.<<StartMigratingSingleDatabase>b__1>d.MoveNext() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.0\50011\src\Raven.Server\Smuggler\Migration\Migrator.cs:line 318
```

"Redacted description" contains a description found in the document. It does not give me an id (i.e. *products-1*), it gives me part of the document. The document has a unique identifier.

After some digging, I retrieved the document, which looks like this:

```
{
  ... other properties
  "Description": "Redacted description",
  ... other properties
  "Localisation": {
    "nl" {
      ... more translated content
      "Redacted description": "dutch translation (which is identical to Redacted description"
      ... more translated content
    },
    "fr": {
      ... more translated content
      "Redacted description": "french translation"
      ... more translated content
    }
  },
  ... more properties
}
```

The ommited properties are not the same as the redacted description, they are dates, amounts, percentages, booleans, tags, etc.

Does anybody know why the database fails on this document?

If I need to provide additional information, I can.

Sorry that I cannot post the actual document, but I do not want to leak any company data. :) My client is too dear to me in these corona times and the GDPR fines just a tad too high for my wallet.

UPDATE:
I have tried option 2, to import from a 3.X database when creating the database. Now I get the following error:

```
[18:13:01 INFO] Path of temporary export file: C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Temp\export-MF.Studio-20201106_181301.ravendump
[18:13:22 INFO] Failed to initialize the storage it is probably been locked by RavenDB.
Error occurred during migration. Exception: System.ApplicationException: The data export tool have exited with code -532462766.
   at Raven.Server.Web.System.AdminDatabasesHandler.<>c__DisplayClass24_1.<<MigrateDatabaseOffline>b__2>d.MoveNext() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.0\50011\src\Raven.Server\Web\System\AdminDatabasesHandler.cs:line 1320. Process pid: 14668, killed: True
System.InvalidOperationException: Error occurred during migration. Exception: System.ApplicationException: The data export tool have exited with code -532462766.
   at Raven.Server.Web.System.AdminDatabasesHandler.<>c__DisplayClass24_1.<<MigrateDatabaseOffline>b__2>d.MoveNext() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.0\50011\src\Raven.Server\Web\System\AdminDatabasesHandler.cs:line 1320. Process pid: 14668, killed: True
   at Raven.Server.Web.System.AdminDatabasesHandler.<>c__DisplayClass24_1.<<MigrateDatabaseOffline>b__2>d.MoveNext() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.0\50011\src\Raven.Server\Web\System\AdminDatabasesHandler.cs:line 1353
```

I have given the user that runs the RavenDB5 service (Local Service) full control of the production database folder (a copy actually, but I tried it with the actual production db folder as well).

I can see that the initialisation creates files on the target location, so it has sufficient rights there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a bug and will require an investigation, if you can provide the dump file (you can anonymize it) send it to support@ravendb.net

To solve the issue, can you try to migrate the data using another option?

1. You can set up one-way replication from 3.5 to 4.x/5.0 the same way you set up replication between 3.5 servers.

In order to allow replication to a secured 4.x/5.0 server, you can modify the config file and add the following configuration options:

Raven/Replication/CertificatePath

Raven/Replication/CertificatePassword (optional)

The certificate must be generated from the 4.x/5.0 server and include permissions for the required databases. (Operator if you need to migrate indexes as well).

2. [create a database from 3.x database or file system data](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/csharp/migration/server/data-migration#how-to-create-a-database-from-3.x-database-or-file-system-data)
3. [live import data from a running instance](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/csharp/migration/server/data-migration#how-to-live-import-data-from-a-running-instance?)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I tried option 3 and got the error. I'll try option 2 tonight after business hours as I'll need to shut the old db down while I do the import. The old files won't be removed or altered with this import, right?
Since this is the first time I work with raven (and there's nobody to help me here), how do I make an anonymous dump file? Is it the output I see in the import window? Is there another file I need to check?

Comment: seems like the document is not in a proper json format, try to run it with some json parser or remove it.

Comment: Holy sh.. There is an object where there is html in the key and it has special characters (\r\n) as well. That is causing the problem. Thank you so much!